# I need help fixing my code, I'm unsure of how to make it give me a total in the very end

Tags: java, loops, math, count, switch-statement

Below is the code I am working on I will show input and the output I receive vs The output I want. I am trying to get the code to give me the total of on-site vs off-site workers at the very end.

```
string name, DOB, status;
int hours;
System.out.print("how many worker: ");
       int number = sr.nextInt();

       int countworker = 0;
       for (int l = 0; l < number; l++) {
     System.out.print("What is ther name ");
           name = sr.next();

           System.out.print("What is their DOB ");
           DOB = sr.next();

           System.out.print("How many hours is he/she working ");
           hour = sr.nextInt();

           System.out.println("What is their Status: fulltime_onsite, parttime_onsite, offsite  ");
           status = sr.next();
int countoffsite = 0, countonsite = 0;

          switch (status) {
case "fulltime_onsite":
    System.out.println("pa " + 3465 ) ; 
    countonsite++;
    break;
case "parttime_onsite":
    System.out.println("pay" + 1305) ) ; 
    countonsitee++;
    break;
case "offsite ":
    System.out.println("pay" + 1620) ) ; 
    countoffsite++;
  break;
}
```

here is my output, I need help having the program tell me in how much students out of the 3 are off-site, and how many are on-site.

```
name: tom
DOB: 12/3/98
hour: 45
status: fulltime_onsite
pay: 3465
name: jerry 
DOB: 3/6/90
hour: 45
status: parttime_onsite
pay: 1305
name: harry
DOB: 6/7/89
hour: 15
status: offsite
pay: 1620
```

I want the code to end with saying

```
Off Site: 1
 On site: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the countonsite, countoffside variables outside the for loop if the display System.out.println() is out side the for loop.

The scope of these variables is local to for loop. Meaning they don't exist after for loop. By placing them outside the for loop will allow you to access the values these variables hold outside the loop. Hence you can use them to display.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting the output as displayed in the question. I believe if you place both the variables outside the for loop should solve the problem.You can print the result later.

```
int countoffsite = 0, countonsite = 0;
```